# IIS 6 Parallel connection limit Web service

Tags: iis, asp-classic, iis-6

Is there any setting in IIS 6 where we can limit number of parallel requests coming from specific host / machine.

I have noticed when a specific web service is invoked from specific server with parallel thread, it times out when parallel thread are more than 10., where as similar works fine when number of parallel thread is limited to 10.

Similar behavior is observed even if requests are coming via Load Balancer to server.

Thanks in anticipation

Answer (score 0):

yes you can, have a look here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/sitedefaults/limits

> The limits element replaces the following IIS 6.0 metabase settings:
>
> ConnectionTimeout
>
> MaxBandwidth
>
> MaxConnections

you may also want to check out this article detailing the steps specifically for IIS6:
https://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/b2b550de-f655-4fb6-9bed-dfc9583b6700.mspx?mfr=true